# Mahout cpu utilization in clustering

Tags: hadoop, cpu, cluster-analysis, mahout

I use mahout to do text clustering

my PC device and software is below

server:
CPU:Intel Xeon E5-2620 2GHz,Ram:64GB

software:
ubuntu-12.4.1 on VirtualBox
hadoop-1.0.4,mahout-0.7

I use canopy algorithm to clustering 80000 txt. But it runs for a long time, just need two or three weeks to finish it, but I had found CPU utilization just below 20%.

I have found someone also has this problem,
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mahout-user/201212.mbox/%3C7959565186420075099@unknownmsgid%3E#archives

but I still doesn't know how to accelerate it, on the other hand, is some parameter setup I got loss? Or is the server is not powerful to run this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop and Mahout are meant for **multiple computers**. On a single host, a software optimized for this kind of operation will likely by much faster.

Hadoop (and Mahout) manage data that is too large to fit into a single computers memory. This requires the data to be stored in files and to be transmitted over the network to other hosts.

Now if you do this approach - repeatedly writing interim results - without the need to do so, you will of course be slower than if you would do everything in-memory.

As your CPU is not fully used, you can probably guess there must be a bottleneck somewhere else. Have a look at your disk IO. This is probably currently your limiting factor.

Comment: hi, thanks your reply. I have check some places. but still not found bottleneck. I will list some parameters setup below.

Comment: In Canopy clustering the bottleneck is usually the distance metric, which one are you using?

Comment: But as I understood the question, the CPU load is < 20%, so it shouldn't be any computation, right?

Comment: I use EuclideanDistanceMeasure t1=300, t2=270,

Comment: I have tried t1=150, t2=100 in little sample(15000), but the result is not well, after some tries, I set t1=300, t2=270.

Comment: I have set some paremeters just below
$ more $MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout
...
JAVA_HEAP_MAX=-Xmx24g
...
MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dhadoop.log.dir=$MAHOUT_LOG_DIR"
MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dhadoop.log.file=$MAHOUT_LOGFILE"
MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dmapred.min.split.size=512MB"
MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dmapred.map.child.java.opts=-Xmx16384m"
MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dmapred.reduce.child.java.opts=-Xmx16384m"
MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dmapred.output.compress=true"
MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dmapred.compress.map.output=true"
MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dmapred.map.tasks=1"

Comment: MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1"
MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dio.sort.factor=30"
MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dio.sort.mb=2048"
MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dio.file.buffer.size=32786"
...

Comment: **how many computers** is the first question to answer. If you are only using a single host, consider using a different software...

Comment: got it...so I need to using multi host to test, I will try it, thanks.